# How to organize the files, to create folders with names extracted from the file names

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, move, subdirectory

I have the following code that works, I use it to group my songs,
but I still need more functionality.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
PushD %~dp0
set "songsPeralbum=2"
set "fcount=0"
set idx=0

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a-d /o:n /b *.wav') do (
    REM echo Processing %%I
    set /a idx=idx %% songsperalbum +1
    if !idx! equ 1 set /a fcount+=1
    md Album-!fcount! 2>nul
    move "%%I" "Album-!fcount!\"
    REM pause
)
```

If possible, I need the following to happen:

```
The song is of the form: Artist name - Song name
```

1. I would like the batch file to search for all songs with the same
   Artist Name
2. to group them in a folder with the name of the FIRST song found from Artist name,
3. in that folder with the name of the song another folder with
   the name of the artist should be created,
4. move the songs, the final files, to the folder with the artist's name.

In the **ALBUMS** folder I have hundreds of songs:

```
Artist name1 - Song Name1.wav
Artist name1 - Song Name2.wav
Artist name2 - Song Name1.wav
Artist name2 - Song Name2.wav
Artist name2 - Song Name3.wav
and the list continue ...
```

I made a folder structure for more clarity.
Need to be like this:

```
───ALBUMS
│   ├───Song Name XXX
│   │   └───Artist Name1
│   │       ├───Artist name1 - Song Name XXX.wav
│   │       └───Artist name1 - Song Name2.wav
│   └───Song Name YYY
│       └───Artist Name2
│           ├───Artist name - Song Name YYY.wav
│           ├───Artist name - Song Name2.wav
│           └───Artist name - Song Name3.wav
```

The batch file will run in a loop until it finishes all the songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directory names are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "tempfile=%temp%\#$#$#$#.$#$"

(
FOR /f "delims=-" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*" '
 ) DO ECHO %%e
)>"%tempfile%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('SORT /r /unique "%tempfile%"') DO (
 SET "song="
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%e-*" ') DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED song (
   SET "song=%%~nc"
   SET "artist=%%b"
   CALL :trim artist
   CALL :trim song
   MD "%sourcedir%\!song!\!artist!"
  )
  move "%sourcedir%\%%b-%%c" "%sourcedir%\!song!\!artist!"
 )
)

DEL "%tempfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:trim
SET "#=!%1!"
:lead
IF "%#:~0,1%"==" " SET "#=%#:~1%"&goto lead
:trail
IF "%#:~-1%"==" " SET "#=%#:~0,-1%"&goto trail
SET "%1=%#%"
GOTO :eof
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Create a tempfile containing artists' names only using the `-` as a delimiter.

Sort that file in reverse-alphabetical order so that `Artist name2` sorts after `Artist name2 & Artist name4` and use the undocumented `/unique` switch to eliminate duplicates.

Then find each file using the artist's name; use `song` as a flag  since both `song` and `artist` need to be trimmed of leading/yrailing spaces. When the artist changes, `(first)song` is cleared. If `song` is not assigned, assign it and trim `artist` and `song` and create the directory.

Suppress the error message on the `md` by appending `2>nul` to that line

Suppress the `move` report by appending `>nul` to that line.

I've fixed the extension-name-in-directory-name problem (set `song` to `%%~nc` instead of `%%c` - treats the string as a filename, & selects just the `name` part without the extension.)

Comment: Thank you! its working! One thing: How can I remove the .wav extension from folder name?

Comment: Hi @Magoo  There is a way to combine this batch file with this you made a few minutes ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73613649/how-to-rename-folders-based-on-text-file-where-names-are-not-in-the-same-order .

Comment: From the folder structure in this thread "Song Name XXX" "Song Name YYY" is the subject of renaming. Are times when I need them separately but also time where I need to happen in one time processing.